# Getting google contacts with javascript

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

How can I get the contacts of a user that has already authenticated using OAuth 2, using Javascript?

The authentication is already made, so I need only how to get the contact list. I have read that Google Contacts Api 1 and 2 had some examples for Javascript codes, but i can't find anything on the Google Contacts V3 site. Could it be that this can no more be done?

Comment: You can use external SDKs to get contacts in an easiest way, like [cloudsponge.com](http://www.cloudsponge.com/contact-importers/gmail). It's has an easy SDK for several languages, a widget importer and support a lot of different contact services. Disclaimer: I work for CloudSponge.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Google Contacts API v3 does not provide a JavaScript SDK.

However, if you want to handle the contact importing on the client-side you can do it with an ajax call :

```
var clientId = 'XXX';
var apiKey = 'XXX';
var scopes = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds';

$(document).on('click', '.js-google_contacts', function() {
   gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
   window.setTimeout(checkAuth, 3);
});

function checkAuth() {
  gapi.auth.authorize({
    client_id: clientId,
    scope: scopes,
    immediate: false
  }, handleAuthResult);
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
  if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
    $.get('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&access_token=' +
           authResult.access_token + '&max-results=700&v=3.0',
      function(response) {
         //Handle Response
      });
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: What is `clientId` and `apiKey`? How do I get those?

Comment: To get those you need to register in the Google Developers Console https://console.developers.google.com

Comment: how can i get google contacts by auth 2.0 ? I have no apiKey.

Comment: I suggest to use hello.js - It makes it very easy to start with Google authentication AND contacts.

Comment: @Tristan Do we need to pay for getting an account in  console.developers.google.com ?

Comment: @Tristan Isn't there a security concern with putting the API key in plaintext? Is there a way to do this so that the API key is not visible to the user?

Comment: Sir whats api key in ur case is it the secret key?

Answer (score 1):

This is what we found to work to get individual data:

```
var response = (JSON.stringify(response.feed.entry[0].gd$email, null, 4));
console.log(response);
```

If you run JSON.stringify(response) you can see all of the headers that you can call on.