# Google Contact API - "Fields query parameter is not supported"

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-contacts-api

Im working on Contact's API with oAuth 2.0.. I want to fetch only a few fields and not the whole dataset. It works fine on the OAuth playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

However, when using Jquery ajax to request it (after getting the token), it gives me the error `Fields query parameter is not supported`. Without the `&fields=` param, it works fine..

Here are the details about the `fields` param:
https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/reference#PartialResponse

Btw, the reason for ajax request is well listed here:
[Getting google contacts with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017487/getting-google-contacts-with-javascript)

Comment: Why not just fetch everything?

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth2 playground works with [Google Contacts API V3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/), and the `fields` param is supposed to work with deprecated API v2 (you can even see a warning in the link you pointed for the `fields` params).

For V3, you cannot specify few fields than allowed. But you can select between a short answer, full answer with default fields, and full answer with extra fields not returned by default.

See [Projection Values](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#Projections).

So, probably you want to request the `thin` Projection Value.

You can see it in action in the Playground using this URL on step 3:

`https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/thin?alt=json`

Pay attention to the `thin`, when most people and tutorials use `full`.

Comment: well, its working on Playground (which you say is V3), but not working on actual calls.. so if its deprecated, it wont work on oAuth2 playground as well....